# Robolectric: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I ran the migration as listed [here](http://robolectric.org/migrating/#migrating-to-40)

After running the tests, I get the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse` with an internal stack trace.

Did anyone encounter this and know how to fix this?

### edit:

Added Gradle dependencies:

```
testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1")
testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:4.1"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:4.1"
```

Comment: its clearly says tha ParallelUniverse Class is not found. assure that you have imported that to your project

Comment: It's an internal crash, and I think I have imported the relevant dependencies. I'll post them up as update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So turns out when we tried running the tests using the "none" option, we couldn't run them because the command was too long. Running with the classpath option simply does not import the rest of the Android environment, but simply runs the test. Running with the "JAR" option gives the correct result, and the test runs as expected
Cheers, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, would have taken years to figure that